# Gitlab runner deletes some files/folders on the server

Tags: django, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm deploying a Django project on **Centos 7** server using **gitlab runner**.

Each time I commit and push the project, gitlab runner tries to remove folders (such as the media folder) that are not in the gitlab repository(are on .gitignore).

> I don't want gitlab runner to delete media files.

How can I ignore deleting some files and folders when gitlab runner starts its job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I've put the media folder `inside` the project in the root static/media,
so every time gitlab runner deletes all the files and folders that are not in the project directory in the gitlab (also the media folder).

Simply, I put that media folder `outside` of the project.

former MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')
```

changed it to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/path-to-some-folder-outside-of-the-project-root/media/'
```

former nginx configuration:

```
location /media/ {
    alias /home/gitlab-runner/builds/path-to-my-project/static/media/ ;
}
```

changed to:

```
location /media/ {
    alias /home/gitlab-runner/builds/path-to-some-folder-outside-of-the-project-root/media/ ;
}
```

Hope it helps anybody that has this problem.